# spring ide and ref hyperlink click doesn't work if bean is defined in different file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-ide

when I have a bean

```
  <bean name="myBean" class="mypackage.myBean">
    <property name="otherBean" ref="otherBeanRef" />
  </bean>
```

and I click on otherBeanRef I'm redirected to definition of otherBeanRef, however this only works if its in the same file.

how to configure spring ide to also support other spring files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both files to the Spring Spring Config File Set.

`Spring Explorer/Properties/Config Sets`